# How do I create a Wordpress author alias?

Tags: wordpress, author

I manage the blog for my company and essentially act as the editor for the posts that come in. Once  they have been reviewed and approved, I load them up into WordPress and publish them.

The problem is that it shows me as the author, and there is nowhere for me to change the author tag to another person, unless they are a registered user on that WordPress account.

I would like to avoid using another plug in, does anyone have a simple solution for this problem? Other than registering all the authors on the site unnecessarily.

Comment: Aren't plugins usually *the* simple solution to problems like this?

Comment: I'm weary of having too many plug ins, in my experience they slow site speed and can sometimes cause issues with the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a lot of userful plugins and well yes some can hog resources while some only run when you want them too. You can install a plugin to change the username and then disable the plugin or simply remove it, most plugins that do SQL changes will not revert the settings back once your uninstall it.

Method 1. `Users > Your Profile`

Your administration profile found under `Users > Your Profile` has various fields and the ones to look out for are:

- First Name
- Second Name
- Nickname
- Display Name

You can change the display name by setting a nick name, this will display the author as your nickname however it will not change the URL `/user/username/` as you may already know.

Method 2. `Screen Options > Author`

The easiest method would to simply add another user to your WordPress site, this can be another administrator or just a contributor. Use the username that you would like the URL alias to appear as, this can't be changed without SQL intervention at a later date, however the display name can.

And if your wondering how to switch the authorship of an page or post this can be done by viewing the post or page that you want to change ownership and then at the top right click screen options, then check author, as by default this is disabled in the view. Then scroll down to the bottom of the page your now see an option to change authorship.

If you decide to go ahead with this method and you plan never to login into the author account then I recommend you set a whopping 256 character long password, any longer your browser will most likely struggle as it does on mine. I use [Passwords Generator](http://passwordsgenerator.net/) and click unbelievable 256.

Method 3. `wp_users > user_login`

You can change the username of any account by editing your SQL database. Using the commandline or phpmyadmin click `wp_users` then look for `user_login` and click it. Change the value from your username to whatever you would like. This hopefully will update all the URLS, if it doesn't then do a SQL database search and replace for all traces of your username, if you used 'admin' then you can't do this as your most likely do damage to your WordPress install.

Method 4. `Plugin username-changer`

If you can't be bothered with any of the methods listed above then you can use a one time only [username changer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=change%20username) and remove it. Your find plenty of these on WordPress plugin library.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion - since I'm *guessing* you're not using the author name as a link to the authors posts, and you only want to use this for display purposes - you could just setup a Custom Field and use that as the Authors name for display purposes.